# Find page number containing item in datatable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a datatable issue !

I am using this vuetify [pagination](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations#introduction) component and this vuetify [datatable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#introduction) component

The use case is simple. The user clicks on a specific item. Next the datatable opens and shows the line corresponding to the clicked item.

---

First, I simply calculated the page number in the datatable using the index of the selected item in my array (making simple calculations to determine the right page using the max number of items per page).

Everything was working well but we added some kind of sorting tool (a vuetify option) and now the lines are not always in the same order than in my array (due to the sorting mechanism).

---

I need a new way to find the page in which the selected item is contained !

(There is a search props availble but it only filters the data. That's not what I want. I need all the lines to be present)

For instance:

```
[
  { item1: 1 },
  { item2: 2 },
  { item3: 3 },
  { item4: 4 },
  { item5: 5 }
]
```

In this case if I have 2 items per page and the user clicks on item 4 then we should open the second page. But now with the sorting mechanism, item 4 could be anywhere :-(

Thx for your help.

Comment: your not explaining yourself very well, but i suspect the answer is that you must maintain the order of the entire list... otherwise it wont work and would random

Comment: my guess is you need to include the sort when passing to the other page.

Comment: I don't get it sorry. Include the sort where ?

Comment: @Seabizkit Do you mean that I should reflect the sort on the original array ?

Comment: is your situation this in a nutshell. you have a page which is in x state(ordered datatable) and when you open a new page you want to have the state (order) which was on the calling page. I know there is probably ajax.. involved but that's irrelevant for now. if so... you need to include the state* in the url which is used to open the new page.. the new page must use this to implement the state u want.